# Построение рейтинга на основе ценности

Tags: алгоритм

Во многих соревновательных мероприятиях часто принято строить рейтинги - игроков, команд, техники, алгоритмов & etc ... При этом место в рейтинге определяется (будем называть "**ценностью**") участника. И вот тут самое интересное. Кто и как определяет ценность? В одних рейтингах просто делят количество побед к поражениям, в других - учитывают и полосу непрерывных побед. В общем, кто на что горазд. Но что стоит участник, который выиграл у всех, у которых нуль побед? Что стоят его победные очки для рейтинга? Наверное же нужно не просто учитывать сколько выиграл, но и кого?!

**Вопрос**

Есть "синтетический" пример, более упрощенный, чем обычно это происходит в жизни. Нужно найти алгоритм вычисления наиболее адекватной `ценности` участника соревнований. Алгоритм можно записать на любом языке программирования, главное - привести словесное описание и доводы, почему именно так, а не иначе.

**Синтетический пример**

Есть участники соревнований [A,B,C,D,E,F,G]. В результате соревнований каждый участник встретился с каждым **два** раза, выиграл или проиграл. Ничьих нет. `Ценность` нужно определить в диапазоне дробных чисел `1.0 - 0.0`, где наиболее ценный получает `1.0`, а наименее ценный `0.0`.  Таблица результатов встреч такова:

[image: Таблица результатов]

PS. В реальности все гораздо сложнее - участники могут вообще не встречаться на момент составления рейтинга, или встречаться гораздо больше, чем два раза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про [рейтинг ELO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BE) - он используется в шахматном мире. Это метод расчёта относительной силы игроков в играх, в которых участвуют двое игроков (например, сёги, го или шахматы).

Также, может быть вам пригодятся другие [Спортивные рейтинги](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B8)